# Problems with C program that replicates `cat` command

Tags: c, linux, windows, unix, terminal

I made a C program that does what `cat` command would do, but i ran into a problem. It works well now when adding multiple files as input. Now it doesn't show what was read at `stdin`, when i don't put any file as a parameter. How can I fix this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<stdarg.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include    "ourhdr.h"
#define BUFFSIZE    8192
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    int n;
    char* index=argv[0];
    char buf[BUFFSIZE];
    if(argc ==1)
    {
        printf("<sintaxa> fisier1 fisier2....\n");
    }
    else
        while(--argc>0)
        {
            if((fd = open(*++argv,O_RDONLY)) == -1)
            {
                printf("%s: %s: No such file or directory\n",index,*argv);
            }
            else
            {
                while((n=read(fd,buf,BUFFSIZE)) > 0)
                    if(write(STDOUT_FILENO,buf,n) != n)
                    {
                        err_sys("write error");
                    }

                if(n<0)
                {
                    err_sys("read error");
                }
                close(fd);
            }
        }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If there's no filename, or if the filename is '-', then do your while loop with fd = STDIN_FILENO.

Comment: @Rup so should i modify the 2nd while and instead of `stdout`  use `stdin` ?

Comment: No, you still want to write data to stdout: you just want to optionally read it from stdin, not a file that you've opened. I'd probably refactor the loop and `if (n<0)` check out into a different function that accepts fd as an argument so you can call it from a few different cases.

Answer (score 1):

[Use the source, Luke](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/bin/cat/cat.c?rev=1.46&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup).  The NetBSD cat.c implementation (see `raw_args` function), starts by initializing a local variable to stdin.  Then it enters the argv loop unconditionally.  If `*argv` is NULL, the local variable is still set, and it reads from stdin.  Else it's overwritten for each argv element.